# Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a basic register script, but when I run it, it seems I cannot create a JSON object constructor. Why is that? And how can I fix it?

Here is the CreateUser Script;

```
public class CreateUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);
        this.setTitle("Create User");
        final EditText username1 = findViewById(R.id.Createusername);
        final EditText password1 = findViewById(R.id.CreatePassword);
        final Switch isAdmin = findViewById(R.id.isadmin);
        final Button createuser = findViewById(R.id.createuserbtn);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response")){
            isAdmin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        createuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String username = username1.getText().toString();
                final String password = password1.getText().toString();
                final String isadmin = isAdmin.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {//error points to here
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);  //and here
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUser.this, MainActivity.class);
                                CreateUser.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateUser.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();


                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateUser.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the RegisterRequest, if you want to see the listener and what it wants;

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.*.*:80/phptesting/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("isAdmin",isAdmin+"");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getparams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

It took me forver to get the URL to work, but when i ran it, i got this error: 
"Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" then it reference my CreateUser class (

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace? Also the json response you are dealing with.

Comment: @VishalArora i cant get the json response, but i can get the logcat, if that is what you are referring to by stacktrace. If you look at the CreateUser script, there is a note where both errors point to

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
at com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response.CreateUser$1$1.onResponse(CreateUser.java:46)
at com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response.CreateUser$1$1.onResponse(CreateUser.java:42)

Comment: It seems like that the response object is not properly formatted to be converted into JSON object.  Try to log the response in logcat using ` public void onResponse(String response) {
Log.d("TAG", response);`

Comment: @VishalArora i dont see anything in the logcat still. Just that error.

Comment: @ِِِAlec Harvey you can debug the code and see what the result is

Comment: @BasilBattikhi the value of responseListener is {CreateUser$1$1@3857} if thats what you wanted

Comment: Im talking about param

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I don't know how to do what you are asking from me, sorry I'm very new to Android Studio